# Show and hide Div using DropDownList in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

what is wrong in this JavaScript code.I want to show and hide Div  On Change() of Drop Down List in asp.net. But it is not work. the problem is that div show but hide immediately.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function ToggleVisible(ddl) {
        var div1 = document.getElementById('div_zam ');
        var div2 = document.getElementById('div_mah');
        var value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        if (value == 2) {
            div1.style.display = "none";
            div2.style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            div1.style.display = "block";
            div2.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>


<asp:DropDownList ID="myddl" runat="server" OnChange="ToggleVisible(this)"
            Width="127px" CssClass="style7" style="font-size: medium" Height="30px" 
             Font-Names="B Nazanin" ValidationGroup="3" AutoPostBack="True" 
            >
             <asp:ListItem Value="0">select</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="1">one</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="2">two</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `autoPostBack="True"` set on the DropDownList. This will trigger a PostBack. That means the entire page is reloaded and the changes you made with javascript are lost.
And you don't need `autoPostBack="True"` anyway since there is no OnSelectedIndexChanged event added to the DropDownList.